# Is there any way to write to a same socket in one process and read responses from another process in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, ipc

I want to try implementing HTTP pipelined requests where one process will be constantly sending requests to the server not waiting for the response and another process will read responses from the socket.

Is there a way in PHP to share a socket between processes?

It seem to be possible to do it in C using UNIX sockets:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-share-socket-between-processes-289978/

I'm afraid that i would have to rewrite it all in multithread capable language like java or better python.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to do what you are asking.  PHP is a fairly linear language and not designed to run in a multi-threaded manor.  Your only real option here is to run multiple script simultaneously but even then the application would be running two separate sockets.  You're better off doing this with Java or some other multi-thread capable language.